# Trying to remove duplicate entries in mySQL database, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a highscore list, that store results from users after they finish a course. The problem is that if people reload the page, their score gets printed in the database again. A quick fix I did was to only select distinct entries to the highscore list. Unfortunately the duplicate username and score still gets printed in the database.

I tried to remove duplicates using this code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tmp (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM score)"; 
$sql = "DELETE FROM score";
$sql = "INSERT INTO score (SELECT * FROM tmp)";
```

Where `tmp` is a temporary table that stores the entries. 
I have also tried to use `TRUNCATE` on line 2, but its not working.

Comment: what is your sample data and sample expected output ?

Comment: What happens when you are more specific about fields - rather than using *?

Comment: If you indicate which columns you're trying to remove duplicates for, we could help further.

Comment: The sample data is usernames defined as VARCHAR and score INT. After I have edited the code I can get the different codelines, I can get them to work independently, but when I try to run them all. I think it only runs the last line.

Comment: Create a unique index on username, then it will be impossible to insert duplicates.

Comment: Actually I try to remove dublicates on both rows, if it makes sense. Entries that both have the same Name and Score.

Comment: Alex Howansky -Thats worked, thanks. But Im still curious why the code dont work.

Comment: couldn't you set both columns as composite primary keys? Well actually it is a similar solution to Alex Howansky's - *preventing insertion of a duplicate instead of removing duplicates after they have been inserted.*

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` returns unique rows based on your selection. When you select all of the columns, it will only exclude rows where all of the column values exactly match another row. If there is a unique column such as a primary key, then each row is guaranteed to be unique, and all rows will be returned.

Comment: I dont have a primary key row such as ID, only Name (VARCHAR) and Score (INT).